# No puedo iniciar TOR desde WSL Ubuntu Console

Tags: ubuntu, windows, wsl

[image: dggd]

Obtengo esto al tratar de iniciar tor desde la consola de ubuntu, alguien me podria ayudar? Estoy en windows 11

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: algo está mal en el fichero /etc/tor/torrc

Comment: @psauleda si hay un error pero no es en ese fichero, es un error en la cookie `CookieAuthentication0` que tiene valor desconocido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edita el fichero:  /etc/tor/torrc

Busca la linea con: CookieAuthentication0

Sustituye por: CookieAuthentication 0

Fíjate en el ejemplo de su github (linea 61): https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/main/src/config/torrc.sample.in